# Unicity of a projective transformation determined by 5 points in $CP^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Consider an ordered set of five points $\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_5\}$ in linear general position in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ and another ordered set of five points $\{q_1, q_2, \dots, q_5\}$, also in linear general position in $\mathbb{CP}^3$. These two sets are of course projectively equivalent, but is there a *unique* projective transformation that will map $p_i$ to $q_i$?

I seem to have an argument for it by translating the problem to mapping ordered sets of 1-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{C}^4$. However, I wish to confirm the result, just in case I may be making some mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the correct word is "uniqueness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is a theorem which say:

> Let $V,W$ be $(n+1)$-dimensional vector spaces further on let $P(V),P(W)$ be two $n$-dimensional projective spaces and assume that 
>   $$
> A_1, \dots,A_{n+2} \in P(V) \quad \text{and} \quad B_1, \dots,B_{n+2} \in P(W)
> $$
>   are in general position. Then there exists a unique projective transformation $f \colon P(V) \to P(W)$ with $f(A_i) = B_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n+2$.

So for $p_1, \dots, p_5 \in \mathbb{CP}^3$ and $q_1, \dots, q_5 \in \mathbb{CP}^3$ which are in general positions, resp. There exists a unique projective transformation $f \colon  \mathbb{CP}^3 \to  \mathbb{CP}^3$ such that $f(p_i) = q_i$ for $i= 1,\dots,5$.